# Google Chrome: How to bring the speed dial page back

Tags: google-chrome

When I open a new tab in Google Chrome, it's being redirected to an unwanted url. I don't know how this has happened, and I can't seem to find the relevant settings to disable the redirection and bring back the old speed dial page. How can I get rid of this?

I am being redirected to http://isearch.avg.com

Comment: Have you tried to wipe your profile.  Of course the behavior you describe sounds like malware is installed on your system.

Comment: You have Malware.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Chrome settings > Search > Manage search engines > Remove AVG from the listed options (there is an X at the end of the line) > pick another search engine > Done.

This link here describes in detail:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653

This is not malware as suggested in the comments. It's AVG's search page.

Comment: There is only Google search engine on the list. As I remember, I removed other search engines from the list a few weeks ago.

Comment: Follow these instructions from AVG themselves
http://www.avg.com/ww-en/secure-search-uninstall
Factory reset might be an option if nothing else works.